# Reload the content in Ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reload

I am trying to make a delete function with Ajax.

```
function delCatItem(catitem){
      var theitem = catitem;
            $.ajax({
        url: "movie/deleteitem/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "movieid" : catitem },
        dataType: "html",
        success: 
        });
          }
```

The function takes an id number from a button and posts it to a model where it finds that item and deletes it from the database. This works. But, I am not sure what to put in the success part so that the content reloads without that item. Thanks!

EDIT

```
<table class="table">
    <?php foreach ($movies as $movie){?>
    <tr>
    <td><button id="item_<?=$movie['movieid'];?>" onClick="delCatItem('<?=$movie['movieid']?>')"class="deletebut">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
    <td><h4><?=$movie['title'];?></h4></td>
    <td><img src="<?=$movie['thumburl'];?>"/></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: What does the content look like? The html? You can use something like `$("#content_container_"+catitem).remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to reload the content, you need to remove the deleted item from the DOM. Without more info about your HTML, I can't be very specific.

```
function delCatItem(catitem){
    var theitem = catitem;
    $.ajax({
        url: "movie/deleteitem/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "movieid" : catitem },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(){
           var selector = '#item_'+catitem;
           $(selector).parents('tr').remove();
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: Being that the container ID is dynamic...not sure how to put that in the script. Put the script in the PHP loop? That doesn't sound right to me...would end up with a lot of repeating scripts.

Comment: You don't need a loop, checkout my updated answer (seeing the HTML helps);

Comment: Works!! Thank you Rob and all of you. ...very simple now that I see it. (This is my first project using Ajax).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, setting `theitem` to `catitem` looks redundant?

But in the success portion add a `function(){}`

```
function delCatItem(catitem)
{
    //var theitem = catitem;
    $.ajax({
        url: "movie/deleteitem/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "movieid" : catitem },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#yourContainer").html(html);
                }
    });
}
```

Your deleteitem script could return the new rowset

Alternatively, use `.done()` like so:

```
function delCatItem(catitem)
{
    //var theitem = catitem;
    $.ajax({
        url: "movie/deleteitem/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "movieid" : catitem },
        dataType: "html"

    }).done(function(html)
    {
        $("#yourContainer").html(html);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice when doing something as you have mentioned is to check task has been completed successfully on server side? just return one flag true or false. if record delete from database (everything goes fine) return true else false and show appropriate message.